# How to I list a shared parameter to a node

Tags: ros, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to list all shared parameter of a node

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9580/how-to-i-list-a-shared-parameter-to-a-node/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-07**:
A node can have private parameters relative to its own namespace. What do you mean by "shared"? Not private? In some other namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

replace NODENAME with your note

for i in `rosparam list | grep NODENAME`; do echo -ne "$i \t"; rosparam get $i; echo -e "";done

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0